# AMP replace accreditations feature

Tags: php, wordpress, carousel, amp-html, rotator

So I've got a website that has a collection of small images and moves them over time (https://deepstore.co.uk - near bottom of the page), I'm tasked with mapping this to AMP which for the most part has worked well (the menu is working...) [image: image rotator]

So I first thought this would be done using AMP carousel but this doesn't have the image area where the selected image is shown. This just rotates and when it gets the end it goes back to the start. Maybe it's an image rotator but I see no such feature for AMP?

My next solution was to use css animate but although it worked on desktop in mobile it didn't work so well (it would show the first few then the rest would have no image.

Any ideas? what would this functionality be called if not a carousel? has anyone here implemented such a thing with AMP or has any useful resources which would point me in the right direction.

Site is on Wordpress and is using the official AMP plugin.

thanks

Comment: Hello did you tried `loop` attribute? in `amp-carousel` ?

Comment: yes I had it animating great with Desktop but on Mobile it broke after a few images are rotated.

Comment: ok, I am not able to access your site at the moment please share your code